# Hide directory from URL

Tags: url, struts2, struts

I am new in Struts. When I create my first Struts project and run it then URL of the project is the following:

```
10.1.21.85:8080/shravan/aboutus/about.jsp
```

But here in URL all paths of JSP pages display i.e my about.jsp page is inside shravan/aboutus folder so how I hide this directory structure in the URL?

Answer (score 0):

First you should keep your JSPs private by putting them inside WEB-INF directory.
Then you have to map an action in struts.xml to show the desired jsp.

```
<struts>
    <package name="default-package" extends="struts-default">
        <action name="about-us">
            <result>/WEB-INF/jsp/aboutus/about.jsp</result>
        </action>
    </package>
</struts>
```

And now your url should look something like this:
http://10.1.21.85:8080/shravan/about-us.action

You have to check in web.xml how is your struts configured to map the urls. 
It could be:
`/*.action, /*.do or simply /*`

Comment: @Shravan you're welcome! :) remember to mark the answer as correct